# How to enable scrolling in Custom Query Web Part as well as library web parts?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, content-query-web-part

I am using several custom query web parts in the front page of the SharePoint site to show data from a sub-site. They are document libraries and blog posts. How can I enable paging or scrolling for the web parts?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.

Edit the master page in SharePoint Designer and add the following style,

```
<style type="text/css">

.ms-wpContentDivSpace 
{
    height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
}

</style>
```